# How to represent a list of text files in Jframe?

Tags: java, list, text, jframe

I am working on an email management application which needs to read all the text files from a particular folder. Now these text files are needed to be presented on Jframe How can I do that? Is JList the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display the names of the files, you should be able to get them using a File object and then, yes, a JList (or even a List) will be greate to show them.

On the other hand, if you want to *read* the files (open them and siplay the text inside), You should look at JTextArea which is disigned to handle big quantities of text

Comment: Well, the names will be displayed in column, one below the other, but obviously, it won't look exactly as in outlook.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only a field, then JList. But if you want to show several fields with information about the files, then you can use a JTable and customize its model. Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).